# Peculiar Java Scope

Tags: java, design-patterns, syntax, scope, initialization

I'm browsing through the Android source, just kind of reading it, and I've come across a strange chunk of code in `Android.Util.JsonReader`. It is as follows:

```
private final List<JsonScope> stack = new ArrayList<JsonScope>();
{
    push(JsonScope.EMPTY_DOCUMENT);
}
```

What is this doing exactly? That is, the scope immediately following the `new` assignment? If I understand correctly, whenever this class, `JsonReader` is instantiated, (not static, right?), `stack` will be initialized here, rather than via a `this.stack = ...` in the constructor, correct?

What then does the scope do? Is that executed after `stack` is initialized? I'm just a bit confused here, as to the name of this pattern, and its use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not related to the new Statement. It is an initializer, kind of like an unnamed parameterless constructor.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.6

They are executed before the constructors of a class in textual order

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5

Comment: What then triggers it? Can their be multiple different ones, presumably after different class fields?

Comment: Thanks, those are some great links. A question though, why does it appear immediately after that particular field? Is it just specific to this class? There are ~6 fields that follow `stack`, before the class constructor, and about the same amount preceding it.

Comment: I'd assume its just there because it manipulates the stack field via the push call.

Comment: You're right it seems, `push` merely does a `stack.add(...)`. So, last question, will this be executed /after/ all of the fields are initialized? Or will it happen in top-down fashion, ie, the first 7 fields are initialized, then the scope is executed, then the next 6 are initialized?

Comment: It will happen in top-down fashion. See step 5 in the second link.

Comment: Gotcha, the first link's quote of "Instance initializers are permitted to refer to the current object via the keyword this (§15.8.3), to use the keyword super (§15.11.2, §15.12), and to use any type variables in scope.", lead me to believe that even though you're allowed to use `this` and `super`, that perhaps it's a little dangerous to do so, as some 'lower' fields may not yet be initialized?